# When I free the dynamically allocated array in C the last value of array is not being freed, its not showing a garbage value

Tags: c, dynamic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArr(int *ptr, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = (int *)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    ptr[0] = 1;
    ptr[1] = 2;
    ptr[2] = 3;
    ptr[3] = 4;

    printArr(ptr, 4);
    free(ptr);
    printArr(ptr, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

1   2   3   4
-362921936  26425   2043    4

**Sorry for noobish question i just started learning about dynamic memory allocation. **

Comment: "*its not showing a garbage value*". That is an incorrect expectation. Calling `free` on memory does not guarantee that the memory is zeroed or set to any particular value. Accessing freed memory is Undefined Behaviour and any results from that are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The memory in question has in fact been freed.  Reading from memory after it has been freed triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

"Garbage" values can be anything, including 0 or whatever might have been there before.

Comment: but everytime its the same value as it was there at 3rd index

Comment: @MihirPatel That's one way undefined behavior can manifest itself.  There's no guarantee that the value read will be anything in particular, including any value that might have been there before.